# ¿Por qué al escribir en un input o seleccionar algo de un<Select> provoca que se renderice varias veces renderizado de un componente? NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs13

Cuando escribo en el primer input, selecciono una materia de las opciones que puse y presiono el botón submit va bien el proyecto y renderiza un componente llamado **Test** pero si escribo otro valor en el input o selecciono otro valor del select **sin presionar el boton submit** vuelve a renderizar el componente . El componente  solo es esto:
export  default  function Test() {
console.log('Hola')
return (
Hola
)
}

Esta parte es donde se maneja la lógica para mostrar el componente  y guardar los datos

```
export default function ContainerNotes() {

  const [generalData, setGeneralData]=useState([])
  const [results, setResults]=useState(false)

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    dniStudent:'',
    subjectStudent:0,
    gradeStudent:''
  })

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(formData.dniStudent !==''){
      setGeneralData([formData])
      setResults(true)

    }else{
      setGeneralData([])
      setResults(false)
      alert('Debes ingresar una cédula')
    }
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    })
  };
```

Parte del formulario principalmente

```
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='flex gap-3 justify-center items-center'>
        <p className='text-lg'>Buscar estudiante:</p>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='False' className='flex gap-3'> 
          <input 
          type='text' 
          placeholder='Cédula del estudiante' 
          className="w-full px-4 py-1 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500"
          name='dniStudent'
          value={formData.dniStudent}
          onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <select className='rounded' name='subjectStudent' value={formData.subjectStudent} onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value={0}>Selecciona una materia</option>
            <option value={1}>Matemáticas</option>
            <option value={2}>Español</option>
            <option value={3}>Ciencias Naturales</option>
            <option value={4}>Historia</option>
            <option value={5}>Geografía</option>
            <option value={6}>Ingles</option>
          </select>
          <input 
          type='number' 
          placeholder='Grado' 
          className="w-full px-4 py-1 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500"
          name='gradeStudent'
          value={formData.gradeStudent}
          onChange={handleChange}
          disabled
          />
          <button type='submit' className='bg-gray-300 px-6 rounded'>Buscar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Sección donde se renderiza el componente

```
      <div className={`w-full bg-white mt-5 rounded ${results? 'hidden':'block'}`}>
        <p className='text-center py-16 text-neutral-500 shadow'>Busca estudiante por su cédula, estudiantes por materia o estudiantes por grado en los campos superiores</p>
      </div>
      {results && 
        <div className={`w-full bg-white mt-5 rounded`}>
          <Test/>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sugiero revisar los temas relacionados al ciclo de vida del componente react y componentes controlados.

El `select` y el `input` están controlados por react tanto en el evento `onChange` y en la propiedad `value` para ambos elementos:

```
<select 
   className='rounded' 
   name='subjectStudent' 
   value={formData.subjectStudent} 
   onChange={handleChange}>
//...
<input 
   type='number' 
  //demas propiedades
          value={formData.gradeStudent}
          onChange={handleChange}
          disabled
          />
```

Cada que el usuario cambie de opción en el `select` o ingrese un caracter en el `input`, react tiene programado ejecutar un re-render con `setFormData`:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    })
  };
```

Por lo tanto, todo el componente `ContainerNotes` y sus componentes leaf/children como `Test` se re-renderizan.

[Ciclo de vida del componente React](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/495126/101408)

[Componentes controlados react](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/509870/101408)